# How to make Imageview bigger than screen size in android?

Tags: android, view, imageview

I'm beginner to android, I want to know how can I upload an image bigger than screen size with the ability to drag it? What layout should I use and how can dragging be done? Just name me what to use and what should I read.

Comment: Where did you get that image from?

Comment: From Drawable folder

Comment: Then upload it right from drawable folder. Nothing to do with size or resolution, layout and dragging.

Comment: I'm sorry my question is not clear, what I mean is how to make Imageview bigger than screen size

Comment: Well why are you still talking about uploading? I cannot follow you.

Comment: Oh, sorry English is not my language. I want to display an image with large dimensions larger than phone screen size, I have to use imageview to hold it and I don't know how to change imageview width and height.

Comment: And that is why I asked for dragging, so I can touch the screen and move  it to see all image parts

Comment: But . You are still talking of uploading. Why? Confusing.

Comment: If you load a big picture in an imageview then you only will see a part of it. I wonder which problem you have with that

Comment: I want to pan around it. To view all parts

Comment: Well ok. But why do you want to make the ImageView bigger?

Comment: I am working on project where I have to display a map, I need big imageview to make it user friendly.

Comment: No you dont need an image view bigger then the screen. You would not even be able to see it. The only thing you want is moving your image inside it.

Comment: The image is large it wont be clear if I did that, I thought I can pan around screen areas to view it.

Comment: You can pan around without needing a bigger imageview was the message.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:padding="14dp"
   android:gravity="center"
   tools:context=".MainActivity">
   <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/iv"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:src="@drawable/image" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Java:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.widget.*;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   private ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector;
   private float mScaleFactor = 1.0f;
   private ImageView imageView;  
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      imageView=findViewById(R.id.iv);
      scaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(this, new ScaleListener());
   }
   @Override
   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
      scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
      return true;
   }
   private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
      @Override
      public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector) {
         mScaleFactor *= scaleGestureDetector.getScaleFactor();
         mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 10.0f));
         imageView.setScaleX(mScaleFactor);
         imageView.setScaleY(mScaleFactor);
         return true;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?